# Problema con servidor Helidon en aplicación Java

Tags: java, servlets

tengo un problema estoy siguiendo un curso de JAVA. Hay que instalar el servidor Helion en una aplicación Java, pero cuando llego aquí :

```
 Routing routing = new Routing.Builder().get("/Items").build();
```

Me responde que Builder tiene un acceso privado, me he ido a su implementación y es correcto:

```
public interface Routing {

public static class Builder implements Rules, io.helidon.common.Builder<Routing> {

    private final RouteListRoutingRules delegate;
    private final List<RequestRouting.ErrorHandlerRecord<?>> errorHandlerRecords;
    private boolean tracingRegistered;

    private Builder() {
                   
       
    }
```

El problema es que en el ejemplo del curso la línea que he puesto no llama a esta clase, sino a un método, os pongo como esta en el curso:

```
Routing routing = new Routing.builder().get("/Items").build();
```

Si os fijais "**Routing.**" llama a un metodo. Pero a mi no me deja, solo me aparece la opción de la clase Builder o rules. En la clase tengo estos import.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import io.helidon.webserver.Routing;
import io.helidon.webserver.ServerConfiguration;
import io.helidon.webserver.WebServer;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
```

Es la primera vez que toco Helion y no se por donde seguir.

Hola Chuidiang, mirando esta mañana la clase si esta el método, solo hay que ir a su implementación en el NeTbeans, lo que pasa que hay dos interfaces en la clase y pense que ya no había más código, mira:

```
 public static Builder builder() {
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Compiled Code">
    /* 0: new           #1                  // class io/helidon/webserver/Routing$Builder
     * 3: dup
     * 4: invokespecial #2                  // Method io/helidon/webserver/Routing$Builder."<init>":()V
     * 7: areturn
     *  */
    // </editor-fold>
}
```

Entonces lo que estaba haciendo mal era el poner el **new** como si instanciara un objeto. Osea hacía esto:

```
 Routing routing = new Routing.Builder().get("/Items").build();
```

Cuando hay que hacerlo así:

```
 Routing routing =  Routing.builder().get("/Items").build();
```

Como el curso son vídeos ayer no me fije. Pero funciona así, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Mirando la API [Routing.Builder](https://helidon.io/docs/v2/apidocs/io.helidon.webserver/io/helidon/webserver/Routing.Builder.html)

la llamada debería ser `Routing.build()...` en vez de `Routing.builder()....`

Saludos.

Comment: Hola @Chuidiang, gracias por tú respuesta. Pero hoy me he fijado como es, si esiste el método builder(), pongo arriba el código.